# How do I replicate this R vector function with Rep in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Here is my code:

```
  df$two <- c(0, rep(1:(nrow(df)-1)%/%120))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic] and read [ask]. This isn't a code conversion service. What parts of this do you already know how to do? Have you made an attempt? Is there a particular part of this line that you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be similar to what you've provided in R:

```py
df["two"] = pd.Series([0] * ((len(df.index) - 1) // 120))
```

WHERE:

- df is a Pandas dataframe with a column named "two"
- An equivalent structure to `c()` in Python is `[]`
- `0` is the value you're replicating
- The expression `(len(df.index) - 1) // 120)` is equivalent to `nrow(df)-1)%/%120`. It gets the number of rows in `df` less one, then performs an integer division (`%/%` -> `//`) by 120.
- The list is put into the pd.Series constructor because it looks like you want to add the final output to the `two` column in `df`.

If you're actually instead looking for a function similar to `rep()`, look at the `repeat()` method from `itertools`. Something like this should get you a similar output:

```py
df["two"] = pd.Series([0, *list(repeat(0, (len(df.index) - 1) // 120))])
```